# My system freezes randomly

Tags: 11.10, gnome, ati

My system freezes randomly while using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox. Mouse works but I
am not able to click anywhere. By pressing ctrl + alt + f1 I can get into command shell
but, there I do not find anything other than a login option.

The only option left with me is going for `sudo poweroff` or reboot.

My system configuration is as follows:

> - Core2Duo 2.0ghz
> - 3GB RAM DDR2
> - 256MB ATI mobility Radeon HD3400
> - 320GB sata hard drive
> - I am using gnome shell with gallium 0.4 amd on rv620 not the restricted ATI raedon drivers.

---

I have also discovered that while scrolling in Firefox/Chrome the CPU usage of Firefox/Chrome and GNOME-Shell increases a lot around 60-80 percent each depending upon the scroll speed.

Also on typing `dmesg` in the terminal at the end I found the following :

```
[  527.824455] software-center[7689]: segfault at 4 ip 08119f10 sp bf9d5690 error 4    in python2.7[8048000+223000] [ 1117.960394] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 3446.888142] CE: hpet increased min_delta_ns to 20113 nsec [ 3682.755118] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4157.184312] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4386.161414] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4458.513696] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4481.456381] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4538.280377] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4565.289503] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 4660.490307] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 5120.940930] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 5191.228400] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 5283.840125] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 5328.562658] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 6565.623439] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id [ 7580.348173] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
```

When the system freezes, pressing super button several times the system logs out to the login screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this could happen. You can try out the following possibilities the next time the situation occurs (switch back to X with <kbd>Ctrl+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>):</kbd>

- There might be a bug in your browser that somehow prevents all input from reaching any application. Try logging in and typing `killall chromium` (or `killall firefox-bin`).
- Have you installed a browser plugin, such as Flash or Java? If so, take note of the
- Your system could experience [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)). When the problem occurs, what are the last three numbers outputted by `uptime`? What's the workload on CPU, memory, and disk? (You can find out with `htop`, which has to be installed, or the built-in `top`. Quit with Q).
- There may be an error in the X.org server. Run `tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see the end of Xorg's log.
- There may be a kernel problem. Type `dmesg` and note the last lines.

In any case, you can try restarting X by executing `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`.

Answer (score 2):

after doing a kernel update by using this ppa:launchpad.net/francisbrwn9/kernels
ppa , i am not getting any more freezes i do not know why but it worked.